# Linq to sql to get the records from parent-child tables

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, linq, linq-to-sql

I have 2 tables (say parent and child table and 1 to many relation), i drag and droped  these tables on .DBML (linq to sql classes). now in the code, i would be able to see the relation in classes as association. parent class has list of child objects. 
my question is can i write a linQ statement to featch a (single) record from parent table and all related records from child table and bind to an object.

```
 Thanks
```

Comment: have you set up foreign keys between the tables, if you have then the association(s) will be set up for you automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to do anything special. Relations are loaded automatically. If you want to iterate over all child objects of a parent object you can do it like so:

```
var parent = objectContext.Parents.First();

foreach(var child in parent.Children)
{
    ...
}
```